# Jekyll site variables not rendering in includes or layouts

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, liquid

I'm working on a Jekyll site with GitHub Pages and have found that `{% include myinclude.html %}` liquid works just fine inside _includes and _layout files. However, when adding elements to the _config.yml such as `author : myusername` and attempting to use them either in the `_layouts/default.html` or `_includes/myinclude.html` as `{{ site.author }}`, the resulting text is just blank. To note, these changes are not committed or pushed and I'm using a local jekyll instance installed on the Linux Subsystem for Windows.

Outside of _includes and _layout in my actual pages the site variables work just fine. Why would the site variables not be displayed? At the moment I have to place the actual values back into the page.

Comment: With no code, it will be difficult to debug.

Comment: Understandable, though I did just figure out that the problem was because I had not restarted the Jekyll instance. Changes to the config don't update like changes to every other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above is the intended behaviour, **every change to _config.yml needs the development server to be restarted to process new settings**.

> The configuration file can't be re-read when using watch, because it
>   contains things like source and destination. It could only work if it
>   were actually like running jekyll build multiple times

[source](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/2302#issuecomment-42323080)

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that edits to the `_config.yml` would update automatically, as Jekyll does for edits to other files, I had not restarted the jekyll instance I originally started. Simply closing the Jekyll instance and starting it back up, with `bundle exec jekyll serve` in my case, read the updated config file and the `{{ site.variables }}` appeared and showed correctly as I expected.

Any changes to the `_config.yml` require restarting the Jekyll instance.